# Search for title of military SF

Tags: story-identification, aliens, hard-sci-fi

I am trying to figure out the title and author of a military SF i read 1-2 years ago (2013/2014).  The human race and its worlds are in a fight with a technology superior race of aliens that are in fact descended from rats and see it as their religious obligation to wipe out humanity.

The main character is a relatively junior space navy officer that is very effective and successful but has some issues with following military hierarchy.  Another key character is a brain in a box - what is left of a handicapped individual that turns into being a military genius that can coordinate simultaneously a spacefleet in full combat.  Then there is a the mysterious race of technology superiors "hunter beings" that you can only handle by not showing any fear an gain their respect.

The end of the 1st book is the moment that earth rejects to capitulate to the demands of the rat aliens despite overwhelming odds and chooses to fight.

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly John Scalzi's *Human Division*, the fifth book in his Old Man's War series, published in 2013 or the sixth book; *The End of All Things*, published in 2015 You have Rafe Daquin, an ex-space pilot as the the brain in the box, who becomes a tactical genius. and Lieut. Harry Wilson, the junior space officer. I don't remember the superior aliens as descended from rats, but they did feel it was obligatory to exterminate the human race.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Definitely not. No brain in a tank in John Scalzi's series is there because of a handicap. The only species there technically superior to humans (and every other spacefaring species) are the Consu, and they are neither on a mission to wipe out any other species nor are they rat-like. Also earth is irrelevant between the first chapter of the first book and the very end of the third, because the colonial union (humans) did put it under a kind of quarantine.

Answer (score 1):

To Honor You Call Us by H. Paul Honsinger

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct story?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You can make this a much better answer if you [edit] in details from the story that match the points in the question.